# Parallax implementation guidance like Sony website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am developing a website using parallax. Just a brief note on what I did so far.
I used the skrollr plugin for generating the parallax effect. With this plugin I was successfully able to move elements with different scroll speeds. However, there are a few major issues I really to resolve.

Given your understanding and guidance I look forward to get through them.

Here is what I am trying to address:

1) The site that I developed is not responsive with parallax. Data attributes for elements are written inline (and thats how so far I think they are written: inline). So  because of that even on screen resize, the inline styling of data attributes remains intact. Hence, the responsive stuff for parallax (on desktop version) is not able to produce same effect on mobile versions.

2) I checked the sony website. Link : http://www.sony.com/be-moved/
They have used parallax and the site is responsive. 
Parallax websites are based more on the imagery content. So, how does the site load faster when the images are of huge sizes. (Running into MBs). The sony website has very heavy images (size running into MBs). How do images of such heavy sizes load so fast?

3) Again, coming back to the sony website. On scrolling the user is shown various perspectives / angles of sony products. So, how are the multiple perspectives of every product captured for scrolling. 
How is such precise sequential image with varying perspective for every product shown on scroll?
Its the entire background image that changes perspective. So, how is that done? Thats not just plain parallax, right? 
I am mentioning this site because its implemented in a differenet way from other simple parallax websites. Sony's implementation is what I am interested in!

4) What would be best to do? Changing background images on scroll(like the way its done on sony) or changing the position of single elements using data attributes?. (like its done on www.numero10.ch)
I have been asked to implement parallax in two ways: 
a) only move the elements within the background. Like if its a sky image with two clouds on the right. Then just consider moving the two clouds to the left on scroll.
or
b) Have different background images with the two right clouds moving to the left. So, that means I will have a volley of images for just moving the clouds from right to left; with every image having two clouds shifting towards left by pixel positions.

Looking forward for a reply. :)

Thanks for your patient reading.

Comment: I don't really see any traditional parallax scrolling effect on that Sony site so I don't get what you mean by "parallax". It's just an animation that advances as you scroll, made of a bunch of relatively low res JPEGs on a canvas.

Comment: Well, the scroll effect is like parallax. Definitely not traditional parallax. But how is even the animation advancing on scroll. Thing is I have a bunch of animators in my team, so I need to take a call if something on the lines of sony website is do-able merging parallax. If yes, please let me know.

Comment: I think sony parallax is pathetic images hanged up slow response and jerky animation why do you want your website to be like this , for the good user experience respose i seuggest use minimal parallax as possible !

Comment: Well I have a bunch of pngs in sequential order. The pngs are generated from a video. Now, I need to place these pngs on my website and create the same video animation on scroll. Sony has exactly done the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2) I believe they use something called "Lazy Loading" which is displaying a "fake" lighter image until all the HTML,CSS,JS is loaded to then load the real images and replace them.

3) That is not mere parallax , they are using the canvas element ( How exactly I don't know but check the page source )

4) It is better to leave an image as a fixed background and work with smaller elements.

Comment: And what can be done with a canvas element? Are you saying the images are drawn on scroll? like the way svgs are created. I have no clear cut thought process in this. :( Please help me.

Comment: https://ihatetomatoes.net/merry-christmallax/ even the tree in this site is created on scroll but this is plain old parallax

Answer (score 1):

I think this will lead you to the right direction: https://ihatetomatoes.net/sonys-be-moved-website-deconstructed/

It explains in detail exactly how the Be Moved website is constructed.

Comment: You can check out more tutorials and links related to canvas frame-by-frame animations. Most of the work involved is manual canvas manipulation - but you can work smartly using images with sequential names and loading them onto canvas using percentage of scroll. Also checkout http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-sprite-animation/. If the answer helps you, please do not forget to upvote and select it as an answer.

Comment: Here's one more that will help you towards understanding more: http://elikirk.com/canvas-based-scroll-controlled-backgroud-video-use-parallax-style-web-design/ (DEMO: http://elikirk.com/demos/canvas-scroll/mouse.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think that site is not just parallax layered scrolling, It is a combination of a sequence of video clips triggered on scrolling. I have not inspected the element of site but I think so. But site is loading tremendously fast compared to other such sites because of your cache in your system and implementation of lighter images in the starting and heavier images at last